# The correct negative form (past participle)

Tags: grammar, adjectives, negation, clauses, participles

I've been searching the answer to my question wherever it is possible, but I haven't managed to get the strict rule (or guideline) for it.

As we know the negative form of the past participle is created by the addition of **not** (Heard - not heard; caught - not caught), but also in the English language there is one other way of creating the negation of such Participles, by dint of attaching prefixes to them, mainly it is **Un-** (Unheard, uncaught, unseen). The latter, with **Un-**, work as adjectives.

Earlier I was quite sure that **Not + participle** is used in long clauses having additional objects, whereas **Prefix + participle** by itself.

For you to have better understanding, there are some examples.

1- We complained but as usual our voices went **unheard**.(Adjective)

2- The robber, **yet not caught by the police**, is said to be armed and particularly dangerous. (Participle clause).

However, there are a couple of cases I'm completely in doubt with. Here they are, below.

3 Our Milky Way galaxy is strewn with billions of planets, alien worlds **still unseen by human eyes** - at least for now.

(This one I found on YouGlish, the phrase is said by a native speaker, but Why **unseen**, I think it should be **not seen** - *still not seen by human eyes*)

4 I managed to sneak into the hall **unnoticed by the security** / **not noticed by the security**

(I think the second one is correct, but on the analogy of the first one I'm not sure.)

5 In the world there are a lot of wonderful places **still untouched and unseen by humans** / **still not touched or seen by humans**.

(Personally, I'd write the second, but, as I said earlier, I have no guideline to answer for certain.)

Hope you'll be able to help me, If there is needed to be any clarification from my side, just let me know.

P.S: Before posting the question I'd read all possible sources however connected to *relustative adjectives* (they are related to the post in some way).  I was baffled mainly because in my mother tongue there is a clear rule for that particular case, and if I wrote an adjective instead of a participle in  such sentences, it would be considered an outrage mistake. As we all know, languages are different and it is stupid to apply the same rules to every one of them. Nonetheless, I am not alone, there is at least one more persone having trouble here; take a look if you will [link](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/use-of-the-past-participle-followed-by-a-prepositional-phrase-beginning-with-%E2%80%98by%E2%80%99.65863/). To tell the truth, I'm quite sure that I'll fail any thorough test on this very theme as the vagueness is none the less. It is very strange that there's no strict rule for this part of grammar.

Comment: First things first: Strict rules are not guidelines. In the US, you can surpass the speed limit by 5 miles and never get a ticket. Or is it 9 on 65? That's a guideline.

Comment: _Unseen_, _unheard_ etc. are adjectives, they are not negative forms of past participles. Although, there are rare verbs like _unsee_ and _unhear_; and they can have the past participle forms. "I can't unsee it" has become a popular meme though.

Comment: "Unseen", "unheard" and "uncaught" can only be adjectives since there are no established corresponding verbs _unsee_, _unhear_, _uncatch_,

Comment: I don't believe there is any such rule. Your Example 2 should read **not yet caught**, and it's written that way because **uncaught** isn't a standard word, not because of the length of the sentence.

Comment: Having said, "unsee" as a verb is creeping into the language, at least informally, as in "I wish I hadn't seen the awful murder scene, but unfortunately there's no way I could unsee it".

Comment: @BillJ , so does it mean that in all the sentences (1. Our Milky Way galaxy... 2. I managed to sneak into.. 3.In the world there are a lot ...) the correct form is "not + past participle"? Therefore I can write, for example, "A mystery remains not revealed by science", right?The grammar aspect is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: @Deeo: you're misinterpreting what BillJ is saying; he's talking about an issue that is only tangentially related to your question.

Comment: @BillJ but "unsee" means to "reverse" having seen something, while something "unseen" has not yet been seen. So the meaning is quite different and not really germane here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both ways are grammatical. In some cases, one form will be more idiomatic than another form, but there is no general rule as to which one you should use.

All the following sentences are correct:

> Our Milky Way galaxy is strewn with billions of planets, alien worlds still unseen by human eyes - at least for now.
> Our Milky Way galaxy is strewn with billions of planets, alien worlds not yet seen by human eyes - at least for now.
> In the world there are a lot of wonderful places still untouched and unseen by humans.
> In the world there are a lot of wonderful places not yet touched or seen by humans.

The reason that you can do this is that in these sentences, *seen, unseen,  noticed, unnoticed, touched, untouched* are adjectives. If you have a past participle in a verb, *not noticed*, you cannot replace it by *unnoticed*. For example,

> *The security guard had unnoticed them,

is truly wrong; you need to use *had not noticed* in that sentence.

For cases where the adjective is an predicative adjunct, the *un-* form is much more idiomatic.

> > I managed to sneak into the hall unnoticed by security.
>
> and not
>
> > *I managed to sneak into the hall not noticed by security.

and

> > In the attic, he could work undisturbed for hours,
>
> and not
>
> > *In the attic, he could work not disturbed for hours.

Comment: Thanks Peter, so in such sentences it's more the matter of choice, and I can  write, for example, "After the meeting a lot of issues remained unnoticed by the board"  as well as "After the meeting a lot of issues remained not noticed by the board", both being equally good, right?

Comment: @Deeo: In this case, *remained unnoticed* is more idiomatic, but they're both grammatical, and I don't think there's a general rule about which one to use (the *un-* form is preferable after *remained, stayed,* and similar verbs, and I believe it's the only one that works after *went*. Both forms are idiomatic after the verb *be*.)

Comment: "I managed to sneak into the hall not noticed by the security." this sounds completely unidiomatic to me (a native Brit) FWIW. I think I would always expect "unnoticed", or else a clause like "without being noticed".

Comment: I think you're right. Let me think about my answer.

Comment: The last examples are not object complements (that’s a word that describes the [predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression) of an object, as in “She painted the barn _red_”). The adjectives here are describing the _subject_, but since they’re not predicative, they’re not subject complements either. There is a term for this specific thing, but my brain is steadfastly refusing to brain at the moment, and the word just will not come to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I don't think I've ever heard of the name for these (although it's possible I might recognize it once I see it). If you think of the term, let me know and I will modify my answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet + Peter, they're predicative adjuncts. They aren't complements because they're not arguments of the verb.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And there's no way of determining syntactically whether they describe the subject or object etc. Consider: *I ate the pizza raw* and *I ate the pizza naked* - though as in those cases the pragmatics usually help out.

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you, that was the combination of words my brain wouldn’t come up with this morning! (Of course, in the sentences given here, there are no direct objects, so there is no ambiguity as to what they describe – you cannot have a predication over something that’s not there. The first example does have a prepositional object that could in theory be the thing described, but if your security team can miss an entire hall, I’d say it’s time for some staff changes.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet or some new glasses.

Comment: To _unnotice_ would mean _to reverse the effect of noticing_, the same way _undo_ means to reverse the effect of doing, or _uncomment_ means to remove comment markers (in source code). Of course, unnoticing is very difficult, except in Discworld.

Answer (score 4):

Where there is the negated adjective, it is *usually* the idiomatic choice:

- 1 We complained but as usual our voices went unheard.
- 1' *We complained but as usual our voices went not heard.

(went unheard / unnoticed / unseen ... are fixed phrases, and by far the more natural-sounding choice. As stated, these are adjectives rather than past participles, which are not used after 'go' / 'went' (*went hit, *went noticed, *go seen ...).

- 2' The robber, as yet unapprehended by the police, is said to be armed and particularly dangerous.
- 2 ?The robber, not yet caught by the police, is said to be armed and particularly dangerous.
- 2'' ?The robber, who has not yet been caught by the police, is said to be armed and particularly dangerous. (sounds more natural than the deleted form)
- 3 Our Milky Way galaxy is strewn with billions of planets, alien worlds still unseen by human eyes.
- 3' Our Milky Way galaxy is strewn with billions of planets, alien worlds still not seen by human eyes. (sounds less idiomatic than (3) or 'which have still not been seen ...')
- 4 ... '[still] unnoticed' or 'still not having been noticed' are more natural
- 5 This has me stumped. I agree, the not-version sounds at least as natural (to my ears). I think it's because 'still unseen by humans' sounds vaguely less natural than 'still not seen by humans'.

Comment: *Went not heard* is unidiomatic. Bur *were not heard* is perfectly fine English. And there are times when the negative adjective is absolutely the wrong thing to use ... Robert Frost did not call his poem *The Road Untaken* for very good reasons.

Comment: But the whole question is about the correctness/idiomaticity of the competing forms.

Comment: "Still unseen" is rather poetic, and "still unseen by man" or "still unseen by human eyes" might be better. But this is straying into style.